# Regext to extract PATH + QUERY + FRAGMENT

Tags: java, regex

For some platform issues, I cannot use java.net.URL

So I am doing this pure regex style:

My goal is to extract "domain" and "path + query + fragment" in a given complete URL. 
I managed to extract the domain with this:

```
            String regex = "^(ww[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,}\\.)";
            String path = request.getResourceRef().getHostIdentifier() +
                    request.getResourceRef().getPath();
            String domain = path.replaceAll(regex, "");
```

However I need to extract the path part which is usually like "/foo/bar" or "/foo?query=123#home" stuff like this. What is the regex to get these parts?

Comment: It looks like your extracted domain will be everything after "www", including the path etc. are sure this works. Also, clarify with examples what you're trying to extract and what you've tried.

Comment: can you put an example to clarify the question (input and expected result ) ?

Comment: `^(([^\:\/\?\#]+)\:)?(\/\/([^\/\?\#]*))?([^\?\#]*)(\?([^\#]*))?(\#(.*))?` |OR| `^(([^:/?#]+):)?(//([^/?#]*))?([^?#]*)(\\?([^#]*))?(#(.*))?` match will give you `0: full url, 2: scheme, 4: authority, 5: path, 7: query, 9: fragment`